# Establecer la posición de inicio para el axis de plotly.graph_objs bar chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, axis, dash

Tengo un gráfico de barras y me gustaría modificar en qué número comienza el eje Y.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que estoy usando la librería `plotly.graph_objs` pero no encontré el doc sobre eso así que intenté usar lo mismo que se puede encontrar en el doc de plotlyexpress. Intenté usar `figure.update_yaxes(tick0=0.7, showticklabels=False)`:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from server import app
import numpy as np

...
traces = []
for i in range(len(dfc)):
    if not np.isnan(dfc.iloc[i].values[0]):
        trace = go.Bar(x=[dfc.iloc[i].name], y=[dfc.iloc[i].values[0]], name=df.iloc[i].name)
        # trace_perceived = go.Bar(x=[dfc.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[-dfc.iloc[i].values[2]], name='Perceived')
        traces.append(trace)
        # traces.append(trace_perceived)
figure={
    'data': traces,
    'layout':
        go.Layout(title='Score de similarité des descriptions avec leurs commentaires', barmode='stack')
}

figure.update_yaxes(tick0=0.7, showticklabels=False)

return figure
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
    * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8051/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020 11:33:18] "←[37mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020 11:33:19] "←[37mGET /_dash-layout HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020 11:33:19] "←[37mGET /_dash-dependencies HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020 11:33:20] "←[37mPOST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1076, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1007, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
    File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\pages\similarity.py", line 67, in update_graph
    figure.update_yaxes(tick0=0.7, showticklabels=False)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_yaxes'
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2020 11:33:20] "←[35m←[1mPOST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Los objetos que provienen de la clase `go.Figure` tienen el método `update_layout` y se le puede pasar los parámetros `xaxis_range` para el eje de las *x* y  `yaxis_range` para el eje de las *y*. Ahí le puedes pasar el rango en el que quieres representar tu conjunto de datos.

En tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
#Actualizamos el rango de las y para que vaya de 20 a 70
figure.update_layout(yaxis_range=[20, 70])
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. Desafortunadamente obtengo un `figure.update_layout(yaxis_range=[70, 90], showticklabels=False)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_layout'`

Comment: Es que acabo de volver a ver tú codigo, y `figure` no proviene del objeto `go.Figure` que es de donde debería de provenir en figura. Ese método debes aplicar al objeto que sea `go.Figure`